# How to set luminati proxy on Selenium Webdriver for chrome in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, automation, webdriver

I want to set **luminati** proxy in webdriver.Chrome  for selenium python.
I have tried using this following command:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

PROXY = '127.0.0.1:24000'

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.http_proxy = PROXY
proxy.ftp_proxy = PROXY
proxy.sslProxy = PROXY
proxy.no_proxy = "localhost" #etc... ;)
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL

#limunati customer info
proxy.socksUsername = 'lum-customer-XXXX-zone-XXXX'
proxy.socksPassword = "XXXX"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

I used my **Luminati** username,zone and password to setup this. But it's not working.

Comment: `But it's not working` - could you provide this in details?

Comment: Page is not loading. it's showing:No Internet
There is something wrong with the proxy server or the address is incorrect.
Try:

Contacting the system admin
Checking the proxy address
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.. but I have a working internet connection

Comment: how did you work this out?

Comment: @BiratBose  are you got the solution ?

Comment: I haven't tried further on this lately @ManaliKagathara. I started using a free proxy network.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# http://username:password@localhost:8080
PROXY = "http://lum-customer-XXXX-zone-XXXX:XXXX@localhost:8080"

# Create a copy of desired capabilities object.
desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
# Change the proxy properties of that copy.
desired_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

# you have to use remote, otherwise you'll have to code it yourself in python to 
# dynamically changing the system proxy preferences
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)
```

from official [resource](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: But it is not using my **luminati** username, password and zone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet. It's work for me with Chrome, but you can replace Chrome by Firefox :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time


PATH = "path to driver"

options = {
    'proxy': 
    {
        'http': 'http://lum-customer-CUST_ID-zone-ZONE_NAME-country-COUNTRY_TARGET:PASSWORD@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225',
        'https': 'https://lum-customer-CUST_ID-zone-ZONE_NAME-country-COUNTRY_TARGET:PASSWORD@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225'
    },
}


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, seleniumwire_options=options)
# If need to add headers to request
# driver.header_overrides = {

# }
driver.get("https://lumtest.com/myip.json")

print(driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML;')) #print page html
time.sleep(3)


driver.quit()
```

Comment: It should be `http` for the proxy URL even for the `https` proxy option.

Answer (score 0):

Likely it's not working because you haven't removed setting of the `proxy.no_proxy = 'localhost'`, that value shall be excluded.

If you haven't used [Python Selenium Luminati Proxy Desired Capabilities](https://gist.github.com/yasinkuyu/eea292dbd848a6246391535e35a7548b) that link before it will be useful ...

Comment: I commented proxy.no_proxy but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
String proxi = "--your proxy url and port";// like 12345:1212
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxi);
    
    //limunati customer info
    proxy.setSocksUsername("Your Username");
    proxy.setSocksPassword("Your Password");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Can you choose location in illuminati? I mean can I choose the location of the proxy?